# Подставить число для выполнения программы Си

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо подставить число в переменную на языке C++ для успешного выполнения программы.
Программа должна вывести "Hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
//  std::string name;
//  std::cout << "What is your name? ";
//  getline (std::cin, name);
//  std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
char unknown = '_здесь_значение_';
   int i=0;
      char r['D'-'C' + unknown];
      for (i='#'-'#'; i<('B'-'A' + unknown); i++)
      {
              r[i]=(char)(('+'-')')*i);
      }

      if ( r[unknown] + r['-'-'+'] + r['='-'<'] + r['>'-'>']  == 12 )
      {
             printf("Hello\n");
      }
      else
      {
             printf("Goodbye\n");
      } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заменим все символы цифрами

```
int main()
{
   char unknown = 3;
   int i=0;

      char r[1 + unknown];
      for (i=0; i<(1 + unknown); i++)
      {
              r[i]=(char)(2*i);
      }

      if ( r[unknown] + r[2] + r[1] + r[0]  == 12 )
      {
             printf("Hello\n");
      }
      else
      {
             printf("Goodbye\n");
      } 
}
```

Заметим, что массив заполняется как `i * 2`, до того числа, которое мы укажем, чтобы получить 12, нам нужен массив размером 4

Answer (score 3):

Заменим символьные константы их кодами

```
char r[68 - 67 + unknown];
for (i = 35 - 35; i<(66 - 65 + unknown); i++)
  r[i]=(char)((43 - 41)*i);

if ( r[unknown] + r[45 - 43] + r[61 - 60] + r[62 - 62]  == 12 )
  printf("Hello\n");
else
  printf("Goodbye\n");
```

А теперь выполним вычисления

```
char r[1 + unknown];
for (i = 0; i < (1 + unknown); i++)
  r[i]=(char)(2 * i);

if ( r[unknown] + r[2] + r[1] + r[0]  == 12 )
  printf("Hello\n");
else
  printf("Goodbye\n");
```

Из этого

```
r[i]=(char)(2 * i);
```

видно, что в массиве содержатся элементы в два раза больше, чем индексы этих элементов. Тогда очевидно, что

```
r[0] == 0
r[1] == 2
r[2] == 4
```

Тогда условие

```
r[unknown] + r[2] + r[1] + r[0]  == 12
```

перепишется в виде

```
r[unknown] + 4 + 2 + 0  == 12
```

или

```
r[unknown] == 6
```

отсюда

```
unknown == 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Запустим

```
bool check(char unknown)
{
   int i=0;
   char * r = new char['D'-'C' + unknown];
      for (i='#'-'#'; i<('B'-'A' + unknown); i++)
      {
              r[i]=(char)(('+'-')')*i);
      }

      if ( r[unknown] + r['-'-'+'] + r['='-'<'] + r['>'-'>']  == 12 )
      {
          delete r;
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
          delete r;
          return false;
      } 
}

int main()
{
    for(int c = 0; c < 256; ++c)
        if (check(c)) cout << c << endl;
}
```

и получим, что подходящее значение -  3. Потом программа вообще слетает, но это уже неважно.